# Python finding min. value in every column in 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have a 2D array, and I would like to find the min. value in every column and minus this min value in every column.

For example,

```
array = [
[1, 2, 4],
[2, 4, 6],
[5, 7, 9]]
```

The smallest values in columns are 1, 2, 4.

I would like the result to be

```
array = [
[0, 0, 0],
[1, 2, 2],
[4, 5, 5]]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: if you have real `numpy.array()` or `pandas.DataFrame()` then you could use `array.min()` or maybe `array.min(axis=???)`. And maybe even `array = array - array.min()`

Comment: Please follow the [numpy documenation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/user/quickstart.html) for basics  `array-array.min(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use real `numpy.array` or `pandas.DataFrame` then you have `arr.min(axis=0)` and `arr - arr.min(axis=0)`

---

For `numpy.array`

```
import numpy as np

data = [
    [1, 2, 4],
    [2, 4, 6],
    [5, 7, 9]
]

arr = np.array(data)

print( arr.min(axis=0) )

print( arr - arr.min(axis=0) )
```

Result

```
[1 2 4]

[[0 0 0]
 [1 2 2]
 [4 5 5]]
```

---

Similar for `pandas.DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [1, 2, 4],
    [2, 4, 6],
    [5, 7, 9]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print( df.min(axis=0) )

print( df - df.min(axis=0) )
```

Result

```
0    1
1    2
2    4
dtype: int64

   0  1  2
0  0  0  0
1  1  2  2
2  4  5  5
```